# Modeling hierarchical data with authentication using DynamoDB

Tags: rest, authentication, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I'm looking for some best practices when it comes to modeling confidential hierarchical data in general and specifically with DynamoDB.

The scenario is best explained with an example: 
Let's say we have a number of `users`. Each `user` has a number of `products`. Each `product` consists of a number of `parts`.

Typical use cases:

- List all `products` for a given `user`
- List all `parts` for a given `product`

So far I have modeled this in DynamoDB like this:

```
Users
----------------
HashKey:  UserId


Products
-------------------
HashKey:  UserId
RangeKey: ProductId


Parts
-------------------
HashKey:  ProductId
RangeKey: PartId
```

The data is confidential and accessed through authenticated REST endpoints where an authentication token can be mapped to a `UserId`. Each user *may* be allowed to view other users' data through some group concept.

Listing all products for a given user is simple since `UserId` is a key in the products table:

`GET /users/111/products` becomes a simple `Query(Table=Products, UserId=111)`

But consider the case of listing all parts for a given product:

`GET /users/111/products/222/parts`

If I simply do a `Query(Table=Parts, ProductId=222)` then I will get the desired data fast, but I am not protecting against other users querying for data belonging to user 111, provided they somehow know about `ProductId` 222 (in reality, ID:s will of course be UUID:s or similar so not so easily guessable):

`GET /users/119/products/222/parts`

... would result in malicious user 119 retrieving data that doesn't belong to him, provided nothing is done to address this.
So here I imagine I need to do something like one of these:

1. First make another query to make sure product 222 in fact belongs to the given user
2. Duplicate the `UserId` in the Parts table and include it in the query condition (which basically means it will match either *all* rows or *no* rows when scanning through the set identified by `ProductId`): `Query(Table=Parts, ProductId=222, UserId=111)`
3. Use UserId as the hash key also in the Parts table and instead keep ProductId as a secondary index
4. Use a composite HashKey such as `UserId_ProductId` ("111_222") on the `Parts` table

If I need to return a 401 as opposed to just empty data, option 1 seems like the only approach. But if we imagine a deeper hierarchy of data, e.g. "users having inboxes having messages having parts having attachments" it seems this approach could eventually be expensive (listing all attachments for part P might result in a query to check that part P belongs to message M, that message M belongs to inbox I and that inbox I belongs to user U, and so on).

Does anyone have any good arguments for which approach is most favorable? Or am I doing something stupid and should be modeling my data in some other way completely?